# Path at MemoryStream for use in CMD

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get the "Path" to a memorystream?
For example if i want to use CMD and point to a filepath, like "C:..." but instead the file is in a memorystream, is it possible to point it there?

I have tried searching on it but i can´t find any clear information on this.

EDIT:

If it helps, the thing i am wanting to access is an image file, a print screen like this:

```
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                var cwebp = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                        FileName = "cwebp.exe",
                        Arguments = string.Format(
                            "-q 100 -lossless -m 6 -alpha_q 100 \"{0}\" -o \"{1}\"", ms, "C:\test.webp")
                    },
                };
                cwebp.Start();
            }

        }
```

and then some random testing to get it to work....

And the thing i want to pass it to is cwebp, a Webp encoder.
Which is why i must use CMD, as i can´t work with it at the C# level, else i wouldn´t have this problem.

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible.

Comment: Sounds like a MemoryMappedFile to me

Comment: From the looks of it, i would have to save it to a file first, then just have it uploaded again to the memory.'

Comment: What's in *your* processes address space isn't available in *other* processes address spaces - it's likely that whatever you do (it sounds like inter-process activity) will have to hit the disk at some point anyway.

Comment: It´s probably Inter-Process if that means working with 2 different programs that can´t cooperate. And yes it will hit the disk at end. But i would prefer it to only hit it for the last part. I could probably use a temp file and such, but i prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is usually protected. If you know where it is, you might be able to grab it with an unsafe pointer. It might be easier to write it to a text file that cmd could read, or push it to Console to read.

Comment: The file i want to pass is a image file, so saving is something i want to prevent, as i would have to save the file just to have it be resaved again(as another format).

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET 4.0 or greater you can use a [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).  I haven't toyed with this class since 4.0 beta.  However, my understanding is its useful for writing memory to disk in cases where you are dealing with large amounts of data or want some level of application memory sharing.

Usage per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes 
        long length = 0x20000000; // 512 megabytes 

        // Create the memory-mapped file. 
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data", FileMode.Open,"ImgA"))
        {
            // Create a random access view, from the 256th megabyte (the offset) 
            // to the 768th megabyte (the offset plus length). 
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
            {
                int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor));
                MyColor color;

                // Make changes to the view. 
                for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
                {
                    accessor.Read(i, out color);
                    color.Brighten(10);
                    accessor.Write(i, ref color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `cwebp.exe` is expecting a filename, there is nothing you can put on the command line that satisfies your criteria.  Anything enough like a file that the external program can open it won't be able to get its data from your program's memory.  There are a few possibilities, but they probably all require changes to `cwebp.exe`:

- You can write to the new process's standard in
- You can create a named pipe from which the process can read your data
- You can create a named shared memory object from which the other process can read

You haven't said why you're avoiding writing to a file, so it's hard to say which is best.