# Integrate bat files in windows form app

Tags: c#

I want to make a windows form app in which with the press of a button will execute the commands of a bat file, but i do not want to have the bat file stored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows a serious lack of detail, specificity, and very little effort. please take a tour through the site help on how to ask a question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please try to reduce the scope of your question, and ask [minimal specific programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I doubt that a Console Process can read a MemoryStream, which seems to be what you were asking.. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912902/path-at-memorystream-for-use-in-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do one of 2 things.
Create the file in a temp space. execute the cmd using process.start. and delete after its execution. you should wait for the command to end.

or you could open cmd with stdin and write the commands to the cmd.

```
public static string Execute(string file, params string[] args)
{
    string argpass = "";
    foreach (string arg in args)
        argpass += "\"" + arg + "\" ";

    var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = file;
    info.Arguments = argpass;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    var p = Process.Start(info);
    p.WaitForExit();
    return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Some think like this using the command

```
File.WriteAllText("TempScript.bat","batch data");
string outp = Execute(cmd,"TempScript.bat");
File.Delete("TempScript.bat");
```